# Rxjs Observable delay stream unit testing in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write a unit test of an Angular service that returns an Observable

```
// MainService
export class MainService {
  connect(): Observable<IData> {
    return this.depService.subscribe().pipe(
      map(res => JSON.parse(res.body))
    );
  }
}

// depService
export class depService {

  subscribe(): Observable<string> {
    return of(data1, data2, data3).pipe(delay(500));
  }
}
```

I tried to write a unit test like this,

```
  it('Testing Delayed Observable', () => {
    const service = TestBed.get(MainService);
    service.connect().subscribe(res => {
      expect(res).toEqual([data1, data2, data3]);
    });
  });
```

I know this is wrong, but the test is always passing because I the test shuts down even before expect logic.
What is the best way to test a service that has dependency on another service that returns a stream????

Comment: There are examples of async testing in https://angular.io/guide/testing

Answer (score 0):

You have basically two options:

1. use the jasmine way for testing async code with `done` callback:

   `it('Testing Delayed Observable', (done) => {
       const service = TestBed.get(MainService);
       service.connect().subscribe(res => {
           expect(res).toEqual([data1, data2, data3]);
           done();
       });
   });`
2. use angular `async` function

   `it('Testing Delayed Observable', async(() => {
       const service = TestBed.get(MainService);
       service.connect().subscribe(res => {
           expect(res).toEqual([data1, data2, data3]);
       });
   }));`

There is more info in [angular guide for testing](https://angular.io/guide/testing).

Comment: I have tried both methods actually, but when JSON.parse function is run, any data after the first data received by MainService is undefined, so it throws an error. The data are not undefined, but seems like because the subscription gets cut off before test finishes, it gets undefined data

Comment: you do `return this.depService.subscribe().pipe()` in the `connect` function. You should not subscribe, just return `this.depService.pipe()`. Your code shouldn't  even compile, but maybe that is just simplified version of your real code.